# react-native run-android stuck 95% when Transforming artifact flipper-0.54.0.aar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

[react-native run-android stuck 95% when Transforming artifact flipper-0.54.0.aar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqkza.jpg)

Comment: What is your question? Please read the following and try to edit your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by downloading flipper-0.54.0.aar package manually

Answer (score 0):

According to your send picture , compile successfully done . but it's can't find Emulator to install app. first open Android studio and run Emulator in `AVD manager` . after your Emulator open run `react-native run-android`.